# Star rating is getting the stars filled from the back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in where based on the default value, it fills the stars. Example, If the number is 3, it fills me 3 stars, but the way the jquery fills it, it leaves me the first two stars empty and it fills me the other three. I have the demo [here](https://codepen.io/Blacksk8ter/pen/qPyKKo). Also, how do I fill a half star if the number is a decimal?

Html Code:

```
<p class="rating" data-default-value="2">
 <!-- data-default-value="@rev.Rating" -->
 <span data-value="5" class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span data-value="4" class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span data-value="3" class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span data-value="2" class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span data-value="1" class="fa fa-star"></span>
</p>
```

And Css:

```
.rated {
border: 1px solid red;
}

.half {
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

And JQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $('.rating').each(function() {
   $(this).find('span').slice(-$(this).data('defaultvalue')
    ).addClass("rated");
   });
 })
```

Comment: Is the issue that it is filling the stars in in reverse order?

Comment: Just check the documentation of [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Comment: Yes, I've tried to change the jquery but nothing seems to work, also I can't get the half star work either

Comment: The best choice for me it is have stars' block with background image with 5 stars. And code changes only size or background position in stars' block.

And you will can show half of star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using slice (I think it's easier to read)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var count = $('.rating').data('defaultValue');

  for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
  {
    $('.rating > span[data-value=' + i + ']').addClass("rated");
    }
 })
```

```css
.rated {
border: 1px solid red;
}

.half {
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p class="rating" data-default-value="2">
 <!-- data-default-value="@rev.Rating" -->
 <span data-value="1" class="fa fa-star">1</span>
 <span data-value="2" class="fa fa-star">2</span>
 <span data-value="3" class="fa fa-star">3</span>
 <span data-value="4" class="fa fa-star">4</span>
 <span data-value="5" class="fa fa-star">5</span>
</p>
```

if you *really* want to use `slice` you can do it this way :
you need to slice the array "between 0 an x". If you use the single parameter call you'll get only the end part of the sliced array. See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) for more information about the `.slice()` method.

```js
    jQuery(function($) {
      var count = $('.rating').data('defaultValue');

        $('.rating > span').slice(0, count).addClass("rated")
        
     })
```

```css
    .rated {
    border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .half {
     border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <p class="rating" data-default-value="2">
     <!-- data-default-value="@rev.Rating" -->
     <span data-value="1" class="fa fa-star">1</span>
     <span data-value="2" class="fa fa-star">2</span>
     <span data-value="3" class="fa fa-star">3</span>
     <span data-value="4" class="fa fa-star">4</span>
     <span data-value="5" class="fa fa-star">5</span>
    </p>
```